# Can't connect to websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, blockchain

I'm new to Blockchain and I want to understand how to use JS to open a Websocket, the code is from **Blockcypher.com** docs https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/dash/?javascript#using-websockets

```
// Get latest unconfirmed transactions live
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://socket.blockcypher.com/v1/dash/main");
var count = 0;
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  var tx = JSON.parse(event.data);
  var shortHash = tx.hash.substring(0, 6) + "...";
  var total = tx.total / 100000000;
  var addrs = tx.addresses.join(", ");
  $('#browser-websocket').before("<div>Unconfirmed transaction " + shortHash + " totalling " + total + "DASH involving addresses " + addrs + "</div>");
  count++;
  if (count > 10) ws.close();
}
ws.onopen = function(event) {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({event: "unconfirmed-tx"}));
}
```

The browser console displays this error: `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://socket.blockcypher.com/v1/dash/main.`

[image]

**Note:** I have a token provided by Blockcypher but the code example they provide doesn't ask for any token. Is the code bad? is it missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your code but with the server not responding as expected.

It could be a server issue or you may need to be pre approved to access the resource (assuming they are whitelisting IP addresses which I doubt).

Also, check out the rest of the code, it has a placeholder for a token that you may need to connect (the error you see now is way before the token is requested).

You can always change the server name to one of many test servers out there like wss://echo.websocket.org and see the error changing from "Can't establish connection" to something related to the rest of the code.